# What's up with classList.add?

Tags: javascript, css

On a project I'm working on, the homepage features its own unique hero image, while the remaining sub-pages will feature a generic image.

I'm trying to add and remove classes (that will fix the position of a nav bar and include padding on the hero) based on the current scroll position.

I can seem to get it going on the homepage, but not on the sub pages. Here's the code:

```
<script>
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar_cont");
var media = document.getElementById("media");
var innerMedia = document.getElementById('media_inner');

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll   position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky");
        media.classList.add("stickyPad");
        innerMedia.classList.add("stickyPad");
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        media.classList.remove("stickyPad");
        innerMedia.classList.remove("stickyPad");
    }
}
</script>
```

I can get classes added and removed for navbar and media, but not for innerMedia. If I swap the order of media and innerMedia however, I can now get it to work with innerMedia but not media.

Any clues would be appreciated!
Jason

Comment: Could you post the html and css? As far as I can see, this should work but without seeing what the styling and structure of the page is, it's unclear where the issue lies.

Comment: That's promising! Thanks for taking a look. Maybe it's based on how the divs are being generated... I'm not sure how helpful the html will be, because we use a platform with proprietary conditionals. But here it is:


https://codepen.io/densecore115/pen/wxvQrM
And based on the condition met (homepage vs non-homepage), then the div and image is served.

Comment: Can't see anything, or am I missing something?

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Just updated my original reply.

Comment: No problem :) could you add the css for stickyPad and sticky into there as well please?

Comment: Of course, and thanks again for taking a look. I've just uploaded the codepen.

Comment: Looking at all of this, I can't see much wrong with it - so as you suggested, it is likely based on how the divs are being generated in your page.

Comment: Thanks for checking that out. Yeah, I've been struggling with this one, and will reach out to the vendor. Thanks again for your help.